# Hide year, month and day in datetime-local input

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, input

I have some `<input type="datetime-local" step="1"/>` input elements, but in my context I only want users to edit hours, minutes or seconds. That is because I set the min and max to `let min = new Date().setHours(0,0,0)` and the max to `let max = new Date()`. So it is impossible for the user the  edit the year, month and day. Here is an example:

[image]

So the 04/10/2017 is disabled because of the min and the max value, but I want to also hide it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you aren't using the `<input type="time" value="12:00">`? Same browser support as `datetime-local`.

Comment: Oh that is what I'm looking for indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
let dateFormat = { hour: 'numeric', minute:'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false };
let currentTime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', dateFormat);

console.log(currentTime);
```

or

```html
<input type="time" step="1"/>
```

Comment: But this is for formatting javascript, I meant formatting the html input element with type datetime-local.

Comment: Why don't you use <input type="time" step="1"/> in your case?